# Linking slicers from PivotTables built with data model

Tags: vba, excel, datamodel

I have a couple of pivot tables that use different caches. All of these tables are created through data connections, and all utilize the data model. What I am trying to created master slicer that filters all of the tables simultaneously.

Using VBA, my thinking is to populate an array of all the visible pivotitems from pivotcache1 (the cache that my master slicer is linked to), and then cycle through this array to filter my other caches (pivotcache2 & pivotcache3).

However, the below code does not work - it breaks down at the For Each loop.

```
Sub FilterMonth()

    Dim sc1, sc2, sc3 As SlicerCache
    Dim si As SlicerItem

    Set sc1 = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_ClickMonth")
    Set sc2 = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Visit_Month1")
    Set sc3 = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Visit_Month")

    For Each si In sc1.SlicerItems
        If si.Selected Then
            'Add to my array
        End If
    Next 

End Sub
```

I believe that this is because there the syntax is different for caches built on data models.

Can anybody confirm this and/or provide me with code to filter all of my datamodel caches?

Answer (score 0):

According to the information I found here https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff839561.aspx, the SlicerItems property will not work directly with a pivot table connected to a data model (OLAP data source). Instead, I need to use SlicerItems with the SlicerCacheLevels object.

Below is a working example.

```
Sub SlicerMonth()

    Dim sc1, sc2, sc3 As SlicerCache
    Dim si As SlicerItem
    Dim sl1 As SlicerCacheLevel
    Dim mnth, nokey, nomatch As String

    Set sc1 = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_ClickMonth")
    Set sc2 = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Visit_Month1")
    Set sc3 = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Visit_Month")

    Set sl1 = sc1.SlicerCacheLevels(1)

    'Clears the strings
    nokey = ""
    nomatch = ""

    'Cycles through the Master Slicer and populates the strings
    For Each si In sl1.SlicerItems
        If si.Selected Then
            mnth = Right(si.Name, 7) '7 becaucse I always have 3 letter months
            nokey = nokey & ",[No Key].[Visit Month]" & mnth
            nomatch = nomatch & ",[No Match].[Visit Month]" & mnth
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next

    'Trims off the first comma for the strings
    nokey = Right(nokey, Len(nokey) - 1)
    nomatch = Right(nomatch, Len(nomatch) - 1)

    'Clears the filter in the slicers
    sc2.ClearManualFilter
    sc3.ClearManualFilter

    'Sets the slicers to match the Master slicer
    sc2.VisibleSlicerItemsList = Array(Split(nokey, ","))
    sc3.VisibleSlicerItemsList = Array(Split(nomatch, ","))


End Sub
```

The only other issue of note (which took me about half a day to figure out) is to make sure that there are no white spaces after the comma when creating the strings (nomatch & nokey).